# Use GnuPlot with latex

Tags: gnuplot, overleaf, gnuplottex

I wanted to plot a graph with log base 2 using my data on latex. It plots a straight line while it should have ploted a curve .

```
    \begin{gnuplot}[terminal = latex, terminaloptions = {size 2.8in,3.0in}]
set mxtics 2
set mytics 2

set key left top


set xrange[1.0:0]
set yrange[1.6:1.62]
set xlabel "User selected parameter $t_0$"
set ylabel "\\rotatebox{90}{Validation Error (\\%)}" 

plot "data" u 1:(log(5)) with linespoint lc "black" title "abc"
```

Can anyone assist me with this? I am plotting this on Overleaf.

Comment: pgfplots and tikz allow you to use gnuplot. Of course, to plot a straight line, you do not need gnuplot.

Comment: @marmot I manually converted the data. It should have plotted a curve. Not sure whats happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant to write `u 1:(log($5))` (note the `$`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}

\begin{document}

\begin{gnuplot}[terminal = latex, terminaloptions = {size 2.8in,3.0in}]
set mxtics 2
set mytics 2

set key left top

set xrange[1.0:0]
set yrange[1.6:1.62]
set xlabel "User selected parameter $t_0$"
set ylabel "\\rotatebox{90}{Validation Error (\\%)}" 

plot "data.dat" u 1:(log($5)) with linespoint lc "black" title "abc"
\end{gnuplot}

\end{document}
```

Here is my made-up `data.dat`.

```
0.0 0 0 0 5.00
0.1 0 0 0 5.01
0.2 0 0 0 5.02
0.3 0 0 0 5.03
0.4 0 0 0 5.02
0.5 0 0 0 5.01
0.6 0 0 0 5.00
0.7 0 0 0 5.01
0.8 0 0 0 5.02
0.9 0 0 0 5.03
1.0 0 0 0 5.02
```

[Live example on Overleaf](https://v1.overleaf.com/read/cjrqsntfdknx)